# Require password to change Cognito email?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I can request an email change for a logged in user without providing a password using the Cogito API, here through a JavaScript function:

```
export function* updateEmail(username: string, email: string) {
    const cognitoUser = getCognitoUser(username);
    const attributes: ICognitoUserAttributeData[] = [{
        Name: 'email',
        Value: email,
    }];

    return yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoUser.getSession((error: Error, session: {}) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributes, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This can allow a malicious actor to change the password of a logged in user who has left his computer unlocked:

- Request email change
- Confirm new email
- Request password change
- Change password

How can this attack be stopped?

Is it possible to have Cognito require a password to request an email change?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make Cognito require a password when changing an email address. You would have to implement that yourself by placing your change email address form behind an extra login step, or something similar